# Using Full .NET API's with NetStandard 1.5

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, .net-standard-1.5

I am using the new `netstandard1.5` target framework in my class library. Are you still able to use pre-processor directives to add additional functionality for the full .NET framework?

For example, I want to use `System.ServiceModel.Syndication` with `netstandard1.5` and at the time of writing, this is only available on .NET 4.5. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can target multiple target frameworks at the same time within the same project.json. One could be `netstandard1.5` while others could be `net45`.

```
  "frameworks": {
    "netstandard1.5": { },
    "net45": {
      "frameworkAssemblies": {
        ...
      }
    }
  }
```

In that case you could "pre-processor" directives for NET_45 and NETSTANDARD1_5. The result would be a nuget package with two implementations (one for `net45` and one for `netstandard1.5` of the same contract (if packed).

You cannot target solely `netstandard1.5` and then use conditional programming to opt-in a `net45` framework assembly.

Comment: Can you please explain the difference between "netcoreapp1.0" and "netstandard1.5"? Thank you so much!

Comment: Sorry, i ve missed this one. http://dotnet.github.io/docs/core-concepts/dnx-migration.html